# How to avoid typecasting leading to full table update?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5, varchar

Is there a way by which update to ALL rows of a Mysql table could be denied or avoided?

Background:

I have a table 'Orders' having 'OrderID' (Type VARCHAR) and 'VendorID' (Type Integer) as two of the columns. If I run the below query on this table, it simply resets VendorID in all the rows:

```
SET `VendorID` = 0 WHERE `OrderID` = 0;
```

OrderID should not be 0 but because of some bug in the system, it escaped all the checks and created havoc. Had OrderID been of Integer type, this query would not have done anything. But since OrderID has alphabets, it could not be set as Integer type.

Can Mysql be configured in such a way that it rejects Updates to all rows? Would result of this query change if underlying database is not Mysql?

My environment:

nginx/1.4.6 Codeigniter (2.x) / Mysql (5.5) / InnoDB table type

Please suggest how this issue could be avoided in future, thanks.

Comment: That would have worked in sql server although the fields would need square brackets [ & ] instead of quotes ' '. If the order id was varchar it would attempt an implicit conversion between varchar and int. If you quoted the zero '0' it would work without any problems.

Comment: Using PostgreSQL you can avoid that but with Mysql I Don't think you could. Some useful infromation : [MySQL will automatically cast INT into VARCHAR/CHAR](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/guidelines-for-sql/writing-code-compliant-with-both-mysql-and-postgresql/mysqlism-mysql-will)

Comment: Yes it could have been avoided if you had used proper string literals for the string column: `WHERE OrderID = '0'`

Comment: The _is_ a way to stop changing "all" rows, but it does not apply for _that_ query.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_safe-updates  (So, I changed title, to keep others from missing the actual use case.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can use small trick

```
update urtable set  `VendorID` = 0 where `OrderID` = 0 and 
(select count(*) from urtable)<>(select count(*) from urtable where `OrderID` = 0)
```